# S3 Folder Containing Redshift Spectrum Table Deleted Randomly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have an external table in Redshift. When I use `UNLOAD` to fill this table, sometimes the S3 folder that contains the data gets deleted randomly (or I couldn’t figure out the reason).

Here's the script I use to fill the external table:

```
UNLOAD  ('SELECT * FROM PUBLIC.TABLE_NAME T1 INNER JOIN EXTERNAL_SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME')
TO      's3://bucket-name/main_folder/folder_that_gets_deleted/'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/my_role'
FORMAT AS PARQUET
CLEANPATH
PARALLEL OFF;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's enough info the question to uniquely identify a solution. What's jumping out to me is: the `CLEANPATH` parameter deletes file that's targeted by `TO`. If something fails elsewhere that causes the UNLOAD not to complete (e.g. if it's a big file, maybe competing resources are slowing things down), then perhaps the `CLEANPATH` deletion completes and no file is created to replace the deleted one.

Perhaps try, instead of `CLEANPATH`, use `ALLOWOVERWRITE`. This parameter means that you overwrite any existing files with the output of the `UNLOAD` command. So if the `UNLOAD` fails then nothing gets deleted.